# pre-populate wtforms text field with values

Tags: python, flask, textfield, wtforms

I can't figure out how to pre-populate a `TextField` with WTForms. I have a field called **organization** that i  defined:

```
organization = TextField('Organization name:')
# I defined also  a function 
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        nameoforganization = session.get('name')
```

How can  i populate TextField **organization** from **nameoforganization**.
Can anybody help me!. Thanks  in advance.

Comment: http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.populate_obj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your form as such in forms.py

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form

class OrganizationForm(Form):
    organization = TextField('Organization name:')
```

In your views.py, you import the form and populate it with the nameoforganization

```
from .forms import OrganizationForm

nameoforganization = session.get('name')

form = OrganizationForm(obj=nameoforganization)
```

or

```
orgForm=OrganizationForm()
orgForm.organization.data = nameoforganization
```

Disclaimer: I didnt test the code - just pseudocode to give you an idea